# Protected web calls when token is not valid

Tags: jwt, azure-active-directory, asp.net-web-api2, microsoft-identity-platform

I use .NET Core 3

I've downloaded Microsoft.Identity.Web from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/aspnetcore3

I use Azure AD to get access to my protected web API. Recently I've switch to Core 3.0 where the issue occures (On 2.2 it worked fine).

Currently when I try to call web api with invalid token I get into

**JwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnostics** class method

```
private static async Task OnAuthenticationFailedAsync(AuthenticationFailedContext context)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"99. Begin {nameof(OnAuthenticationFailedAsync)}");
    // Place a breakpoint here and examine context.Exception
    await s_onAuthenticationFailed(context).ConfigureAwait(false);
    Debug.WriteLine($"99. End - {nameof(OnAuthenticationFailedAsync)}");
}
```

which is absolutely right, since the token is invalid. But after that my protected controller methods calls anyway (I call them from postman by add header with Bearer and the token).
Here's my controller:

```
    [Route("api/Points")]
    [ApiController]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "AzureAD")]
    public class InstallationPointController : ControllerBase
{
...
}
```

Setup for AD authorization in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddProtectedWebApi(Configuration,subscribeToJwtBearerMiddlewareDiagnosticsEvents:true)
    .AddProtectedApiCallsWebApis(Configuration, new []{ "user.read", "offline_access" }).AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

**Update**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Comment: Have you remembered to add `app.UseAuthorization()` to the middleware pipeline?

Comment: @juunas Yes. I've update my post.

Comment: Just an update, Microsoft.Identity.Web is now a NuGet package. We encourage its usage to keep your library updated and with bug fixed. [Microsoft.Identity.Web wiki](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of your middleware is wrong. Routing needs to be before authentication and authorisation.

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One observation, I noticed that you are using the scheme value `AzureAD`. Currently, Microsoft.Identity.Web uses `OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` as a default scheme (which has *OpenIdConnect* as its value).

If you want to use a different scheme name with Microsoft.Identity.Web, you can use the following method:

```cs
   services.AddAuthentication("MyScheme")
     .AddSignIn(Configuration);
```